# TNSNAMES.ORA order of IP addrsses

Tags: c#, oracle19c, tnsnames

I am using tnsnames.ora for my Oracle database connection. DB servers are clustered so tns names entry looks like:

```
ABCD = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (FAILOVER = on) 
      (LOAD_BALANCE = off) 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.4)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.5)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.2.3.10)(PORT = 1521))
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVICE_NAME = abcd) 
      (FAILOVER_MODE = 
        (TYPE = SELECT) 
        (METHOD = BASIC) 
      ) 
   ) 
)
```

Supposedly, if 1.2.3.4 does not respond, it is to failover and try 1.2.3.5, but it doesn't.

Even if 1.2.3.5 is online and .4 is offline, I get oracle connection error. When I change the order and put .5 on top, connection error goes away.

In web.config, connection string is defined as:

```
<add name="ABCDConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=ABCD;User Id=my_id;Password=my_pwd;" providerName="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
```

Am I missing something when trying to use this tns names entry? I am pretty sure changing the order is not the solution as it defeats the purpose of having failover.

Comment: Presumably this is an Oracle RAC configuration? Have you been provided with a SCAN DNS name by the DBA? Are the addresses in your tnsnames.ora the physical or virtual IP addresses for each cluster node?

Comment: If this is RAC, switch to using single SCAN IP address. If not, please note that in case of JDBC drivers this feature is buggy as hell. You need to upgrade to most recent 19c/21c drivers in order to make it working.

Comment: I will discuss with DBA if it is possible to get a single SCAN DNS name. What I don't understand is why it works/connects when I change the order of IP addresses. I tested with SQL Developer and see that using 1.2.3.4 fails but 1.2.3.5 works. Now, if I change tns names entry and put 1.2.3.5 before 1.2.3.4, application connects to DB; if I leave it as is, it throws DB connection error. DB is 21c but not sure what version client is, probably 12c.

Comment: Also, IP addresses are physical and not virtual.

Comment: @NoBullMan In general you should always use virtual IPs when connecting to RAC: use the SCAN name if possible. If not the SCAN name, then use the SCAN IP addresses in round-robin/load balanced order rather than failover. If all else fails use the virtual IPs for each node. Those options put the onus of service failover on the *server* rather than on the client *and* the server. With RAC there should never be a virtual IP that is completely down, regardless of individual node status.

Comment: Checked with DBA, it is not RAC and those IPs are actually SCAN IPs. I found that the issue was with connection timeout, which by default is 15 seconds. When I ran "sqlplus some_user/some_pwd@ABCD", it took 30-40 seconds to connect, using above order of IP addresses, but it did eventually connect. Because of 15 seconds default timeout, my application would timeout before going through entire set of IPs. Once I set connection timeout to 60 seconds in web.config, it worked. Thank you for everyone's comments as I learned something new today (SCAN DNS and SCAN IP)